# creation event for userObject

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, delegates

I have an object - simple table. I want to realize method of event OnClick for this object. Table doesn't have any onclick methods default. I tried to make it with delegates and events, but I have some troubles and my code doesn't work:

```
public class CustomEvent
{
    public delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e);

    public event MyEventHandler MyEventClick;

    public void OnMyEventClick(MyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyEventClick != null) MyEventClick(this, e);
    }
}

public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private string result;

    public string Result
    {
        set { result = value; }
        get { return result; }
    }

    public MyEventArgs(string result)
    {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

and

```
table.MyEventClick += new CustomEvent.MyEventHandler(table_MyEventClick);
```

Here IntelliSense doesn't see MyEventClick. And when I build this code VS gives me an error: **The type or namespace name 'MyEventHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

How is it possible to solve this problem? 

BTW, I found another method to do it with javascript:

```
table.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location.href='default.aspx'; return false;");
```

but I woould like to do it with c#. 
Regards.

Comment: this is invalid: `new CustomEvent.MyEventHandler` it seems you confused about events.There is no way to do something like `"table.MyEventClick"` unless you create your own class by inheriting from Table class.then you should define your event handler inside of that class.

Comment: yes, you are right. I didn't understand properly about events. I have just written some examples with delegates and events and looked for my mistakes and studied sequence of operations.

Comment: Selman22 is right... this `table.Attributes.Add("onclick", "location.href='default.aspx'; return false;");` add a client side onclick handler, and absolutely is different with your first part of the codes (event and delegates)(this is a way to define server side event for your objects(and also not for built in objects))